# Joining on two columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a table in SQL server like this:

```
ID Search
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

And another like this:

```
ID   ID_a
1     2
1     3
2     4 
2     3
```

Basically want to join them and receive smth like:

```
   Search  Search_a
    a        b
    a        c
    b        d
    b        c
```

Can do it for the first column using join but how to do it for both?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint:  You use two joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two join to first table with diff alias.

Sample below

```
SELECT t1.Search,t2.Search as Search_a
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON table2.col1 = t1.col1
INNER JOIN table1 AS t2 ON table2.col2 = t2.col1
```